# Convert minutes to integer in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a list of measurements taken at regular time intervals and need to do calculations using the minute values from the intervals
So for example I have

| Time |
| --- |
| 01:15 |
| 01:30 |

I want to extract the 15 minutes as a number so I can plug it into a formula as fifteen but it either stays in time format or converts to decimal

Answer (score 1):

### Extracting the Minutes and Converting it to Integer

I have 2 formulas for you to try depending on your use case. Please let me know if there is any need for further clarification.

Formula to Extra the Minute from the Time Value:

```
=MINUTE(A2)
```

or  alternatively to get the Decimal Value of the Minute on the Hour.

```
 =MINUTE(A2)/60
```

This is assuming that A2 is where your Time Value is.

### Reference:

[Minute Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093048?hl=en)

*

> Take note that I have created this answer generally to show you how to extract the minutes on a time value that you can work with. Generally if you have questions please don't hesitate to comment if you have questions.

- 

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: MINUTE works but I have to dedicate an entire cell to it and then call that cell when I need it in a formula for it to return the correct value.

Comment: for example I'd like to do 2*MINUTE(A2-A1) and get back 30

Comment: You can use the minute function to directly use the minutes in a formula without using additional cell. I have test it out and it works please let me know if you encounter anything that you need the communities help you can also provide a minimum reproducible sample that showcase your expected result and how you data works so the community will have better grasp of you use case.

Comment: Something like `=2*(MINUTE(A2)-MINUTE(A1))` doesn't suit you?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear your request. You need to convert 01:15 to 00:15?, maintaining only the minutes. If that's so, constructing over @Babanana's, given one day is equal to 1 in date format, you can get the correct fraction to convert it to time format by dividing by 24 and 60 (1440):

```
=MINUTE(A2)/1440
```

And give it the format you need

Comment: I am also with @Martin on this his formula is getting the minute on the day and converting it to decimal point.  If you need further help please provide information and more details about your use case.